# Approve and unlock a record after some time

Tags: trigger, approval-process

I have a scenario where I have to auto approve a record 30 min(say) after  submitting the approval and the record should be unlocked.

I planned to do this by using workflow rule and a trigger combination.
Update a field using time triggered workflow and use trigger to approve on basis of workflow's field update? But my concern is, how do i unlock or approve a record from trigger? do I query it from somewhere or where do I get the pending approvals in the trigger?

Let me know if I'm choosing a wrong approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can lock/unlock records using the new [Lock/Unlock a record in Apex](http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/rn_apex_approval_locks_unlocks.htm#rn_apex_approval_locks_unlocks). You can use the [Approval Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_approval.htm) to unlock the record. For example, you might start off like this:

```
Id[] unlockRecordIds = new Id[0];
for(SObject record: Trigger.new) {
    if(recordShouldUnlock(record)) {
        unlockRecordIds.add(record.Id);
    }
}
Approval.UnlockResult[] results = Approval.unlock(unlockRecordIds, false);
// Handle errors here
```